# Decommissioning multiple Hadoop DataNodes in parallel

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I'm replacing multiple machines in my Hadoop CDH 5.7 cluster.
I started by adding a few new machines and decommission same amount of existing datanodes.

I noticed that blocks are marked as under-replicated when decommissioning a node.

Does it mean I'm at risk when decommissioning multiple nodes?
Can I decommission all nodes in parallel?
Is there a better way of replacing all machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its obvious that when a node is down(or removed) the data is under-replicated.
When you add a new node and rebalance this will automatically be fixed.

#### What's actually happening?

Lets say the replication factor on your cluster is 3. When a node is decommissioned, all the data stored on it is gone and the replication factor of that data is now 2 (and hence under replicated). Now when you add a new node and re-balance the missing copy is made again hence restoring the replication to the default.

#### Am I at risk?

Not if you are doing it one by one.
**That is replace a node and re-balance cluster. Repeat.** (*I think this is the only way!* )

If you just remove multiple nodes there is good chance of losing data as you may lose all replications of some data(which resided on those nodes).

***Don't decommission multiple nodes at once!***